# startx stops working when I modify /home/pi/.profile

Tags: startx

I added the following lines to `/home/pi/.profile`

```
clear
cd /
cd /home/pi/circulation_of_circuits/    
./launcher.sh
```

In case it matters, `launcher.sh` contains this:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /
cd home/pi/circulation_of_circuits
clear
python c_of_c.py
```

When I type `startx` I goes to a black screen.
When I remove the added lines from `/home/pi/.profile` I can go to startx again.

Why does this happen? And how can I call the script without breaking startx?

(p.s. the same happens for `/etc/profile`)